# Python dataframes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, difflib

I have a dataframe (df) and trying to append data to a specific row

`Index   Fruit   Rank
0        banana    1
1        apple     2
2        mango     3
3        Melon     4`

The goal is to compare the Fruit at Rank 1 to each rank and then append the value.
I'm using difflib.SequenceMatcher to make the comparison. Right now i'm able to append to df but i end up appending the same value to each row. I'm struggling with the loop and append.
Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is some of my code:

```
new_entry = df[(df.Rank ==1)]
new_fruit = new_entry['Fruit']

prev_entry = df[(df.Rank ==2)]
prev_fruit = prev_entry['Fruit']


similarity_score = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, str(new_fruit).lower(), str(prev_fruit).lower()).ratio()

df['similarity_score'] = similarity_score
```

The result is something like this:

`Index   Fruit   Rank  similarity_score
0        banana    1      0.3
1        apple     2      0.3
2        mango     3      0.3
3        Melon     4      0.3`

The desired result is:

`Index   Fruit   Rank   similarity_score
0        banana    1      n/a
1        apple     2      0.4 
2        mango     3      0.5
3        Melon     4      0.6`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't give the similarity score order you want, but it calculates the `SequenceMatcher` ratio to the rank 1 value ('banana') and each row and adds it as a column.

```
import pandas as pd
import difflib

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': ['banana', 'apple', 'mango', 'melon'],
                   'Rank': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

top = df['Fruit'][df.Rank == 1][0]
df['similarity_score'] = df['Fruit'].apply(lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(
                                           None, top, x).ratio())
```